# Spider identification North-West Italy

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I would like to know what kind of spider is the one I killed and if it is somehow dangerous.

- Location: **city in North-West Italy**.
- Dimensions: **~1.5 cm, with legs opened**.
- Time of day: **around midday**, but the external jalousie of my window was closed, so it was dark when I found it.

It seemed to have some sort of **marking on its abdomen**, but colors were very dark, so it was difficult to view it properly.

Edit: The marking was some sort of symmetrical shape covering quite all the abdomen. Colors were very dark and it was difficult to distinguish it properly from the rest of the abdomen.

[image]

Unfortunately I didn't photograph it when was alive, and intact, because I found it out of my window and I didn't want to lose its tracks while getting my phone.

For what I know, the most dangerous spider that can be found here is the *Loxosceles rufescens* (Mediterranean recluse spider); it seems different, but obviously I'm not an expert.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You've done a good job on supplying the information needed for ids, but I'm not sure what you mean by a "form on its abdomen". Do you mean a marking and if so is it a different color, texture, or something else? Any additional information you can [edit] into your post will increase the chances of getting an accurate id.

Comment: Here is a gallery of species observed and submitted to the iNaturalist website... filtered the species by limiting the search to 'typical spiders' (excludes tarantulas or other weird things) and limiting the search to NW Italy. Sorted by most-commonly observed first. You can click on the "N Observations" to see the submitted photos that are currently IDed to that species (not necessarily a correct ID) https://inaturalist.ca/observations?nelat=46&nelng=13&place_id=any&subview=map&swlat=42&swlng=4.5&taxon_id=120474&view=species